# add namespace tag to root element asmx C#

Tags: soap, asmx, xml-namespaces

Good day.

i am hoping someone could possibly assist me. i am creating an asmx web service. i have written all the classes to send a response back in soap xml. i only have one issue currently that i cannot seem to overcome. i have done quite a bit searching and have tried several options but have not managed to make the desired changes i need.

i require that the root node has an namespace tag, but i cannot figure out how to achieve this. currently i get an output like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <RequestResponse xmlns="https://web.com/">
            <RequestResult>
                <ServerVersion>1.0</ServerVersion>
            </RequestResult>
        </RequestResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

but i require the format in with the following.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns:RequestResponse xmlns:ns="https://web.com/">
            <RequestResult>
                <ServerVersion>1.0</ServerVersion>
            </RequestResult>
        </ns:RequestResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

i require **<ns:RequestResponse xmlns:ns="https://web.com/">** "ns:tag"

my class looks like the below.

```
namespace Requester
{
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "https://web.com/")]
    public class RequestResponse
    {
      
        public string ServerVersion
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see, i have tried adding the XMLRoot and Namespace,  but the output remains the same.
i have seen on many places that it is not really required, but i have a client who insists this be in place. i have even seen this article by Scott Hanselman which seems to be exactly what i am looking for.
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/XmlRootForcePrefixPrefixfoo.aspx

any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
i have looked over a good number of pages here on Stack overflow but none have helped me achieve this change thus far. i apologies if this is a duplicate, however i cannot get the desired change